# Stand alone Application for Retrieving data from 8 ontology files(.ttl files) and displaying the output in json

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology

I am new to semantic web. I spent lot of time in understanding the concepts of semantic web i.e. RDF,ontology,ontology mapping etc. Now I have a task to retrieve the data from 8 ontology files and display the output in json format. I will explain the problem in detail.

I was given 8 ontology files(.ttl files) which represents the information of the persons in an organisation. Now the out put must include the information regarding all the persons in the company with their personal information like first name ,last name, country, age etc. The application must be a Standalone application.

For that I think we need to combine all the ontology files and use some APIs but I am not sure. Please help me.

Rakesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the easiest way to do this is by using an RDF toolkit/framework. There are tons of different RDF toolkits and APIs available (e.g. Jena or Sesame in Java, dotNetRdf in .Net, Redland in C, etc.). Which one you pick depends on which programming environment you are most comfortable in. So: choose one, work through its documentation/tutorials, and try and get a simple app going. If you get stuck, ask a new question, but please be specific: show what you've tried.

Comment: Jeen, thanks a lot for your reply. I will try to implement these. I have a small question. I need to get the output in JSON. can I achieve this by using jena

Comment: Not sure if Jena provides JSON output out of the box, but you can quite easily stick any Java JSON library on top (Google Gson is good) and do a bit of programming yourself to combine the two.