# Extract Triples from multiple ontology files(ttl files) in java

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology, rdfs

I have 8 ontology files(ttl files). My task is to extract all the triples from it and display the output with all the properties. The task must be done in java. looking forward for your reply.

Rakesh

Comment: This is basically the same question you asked before. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305927/stand-alone-application-for-retrieving-data-from-8-ontology-files-ttl-files-an . You got an answer there, which you even accepted. So why the new question?

Answer (score 4):

[Jena](http://jena.apache.org) or [RDF4J](http://rdf4j.org) (formerly known as Sesame) are your two best bets for working with RDF in Java.  I prefer RDF4J over Jena; I find it easier to use because it's more lightweight, but ymmv.  Jena provides a simple [tutorial](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/index.html) that will show you the basics of the API, and [here](https://rdf4j.org/documentation/programming/rio/) is an article on how to use RDF4J RIO to read & write RDF.